# Check if some polygons overlap each other

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to determine if some polygons overlap each other. All the polygons are in the same layer.

The PostGis function ST_OVERLAPS can determine if two geometric element overlap. But I can't found a way to apply this function in order to check if one or more polygons overlap each other.

I would like something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyGeometricTable g
WHERE ST_OVERLAPS(g.geom,g.geom) = 1
AND g.id <> g.id                      --The polygon that overlap another polygon is not the same.
```

MyGeomtricTable contains for examples 100 polygons.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do this with Descartes multiplication, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyGeometricTable g1, MyGeometricTable g2
WHERE ST_OVERLAPS(g1.geom,g2.geom) = TRUE 
AND g1.id <> g2.id;
```

To apply John Barça's improvement, we can do the following:

```
select g1.id, g2.id
from MyGeometricTable g1, MyGeometricTable g2
where ST_OVERLAPS(g1.geom,g2.geom) = TRUE
AND g1.id > g2.id
```

Comment: Even better, you can cut the run time in half with `Select g1.id .... AND gi.id > g2.id;`

Comment: @JohnBarça, you are right, I edited my answer accordingly